# How can I convert a char/string in JS to uint8?

Tags: node.js

Say I have a str char:

```
const s = '\n';
```

how can I convert to uint8? I believe the right value is 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html) using [`Buffer.from()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe). That will give you a `Buffer` instance, from that you can use [`Buffer.readUInt8()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint8_offset) to get the UInt8 representation of the Buffer.

```
function stringToUInt8 (s, offset) { 
  return Buffer.from(s).readUInt8(offset)
}

console.log(stringToUInt8('\n'))
```

Comment: yeah I guess this works too: `Buffer.from('\n').values().next()` or maybe not? Idk

Comment: @MrCholo it appears that works similarly but returns an `Iterator`, if you don't need an `Iterator` then I wouldn't use it. `readUInt8()` works exactly as you want, no need to introduce the `Iterator` abstraction.

Comment: yeah true, the Iterator is wasted basically yeah